# Can`t get dynamic html height in WebView in iOS

Tags: ios

We use HandleBar js lib to generate dynamic html, after iOS WebView load up the Html.It only get the template, the height is not right. After a while, the images in template have loaded.the page is fulfilled. But I can`t get the height.

I`ve tried serval methods below:

> 1

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    _webViewHeight = [[_webView_wares stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] integerValue];


    if (_webViewHeight > 0)
    {
        _webView_wares.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, KSCREEN_WIDTH, _webViewHeight);

        [_webView_wares sizeToFit];

        NSLog(@"webViewHeight高度:%ld",(long)_webViewHeight);

        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}
```

> 2

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"])
    {
        NSInteger nextHeight  = [[_webView_wares stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] integerValue];


        if (_webViewHeight < nextHeight)
        {
            _webViewHeight = nextHeight;
            CGRect newFrame      = _webView_wares.frame;
            newFrame.size.height = _webViewHeight;
            _webView_wares.frame = newFrame;

            [_webView_wares sizeToFit];
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
}
```

But none of the above get the correct height. Somebody Help me!

Answer (score 0):

If your using auto layout then set height constraint to web view and create outlet of this constraints

**Variable**

```
float  heightWebview=0;
UIWebView *objWebView;
```

**Pass HTML string to WebView (Write in cellForRowAtIndexPath)**

```
objWebView = [UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, heightWebview)
[objWebView loadHTMLString:<Pass your HTML string> baseURL:nil];
```

**WebView Delegate Methods**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  NSLog(@"Height Webview: %f", objWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
  heightWebview=objWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
  [objTableView reloadData];
}
```

**Add this two table view delegate methods**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0;
}
```

Comment: I ‘not using storyboard   I‘m using pure code  TableViewCell  insert  WebView .  i need get the height of webView when it fished load .then update the height of cell to adapted to the layout!  thank you for help me!